# Rotating 2D graph like if it were in 3D

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, graphics3d, style

I want to rotate graph plotted in 2D like if it were in 3D - around any axis `x, y, z`.

The following code allows me to rotate only inside `xy` plane. The quality of images is excellent.

```
m=5;
g=GridGraph[{m,m},VertexCoordinates->({#[[1]],#[[2]]}&/@((Tuples[Range[m]-1,2]-(m-1)/2)/(m-1))),GraphHighlightStyle->"Thick"];
HighlightGraph[g,PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g,9,17]]]
Rotate[%,\[Pi]/4]
Clear[g,m]
```

[image]
[image]

Now I can modify the graph to be in 3D, then I can rotate it in 3D, but then I do not like the style of the graph esthetically. Rotations also changes color of vertices and edges because of lighting which I do not like too.

So my question is **how to rotate original 2D graph not only in `xy` plane but also around `x` and `y` axis and preserve the same style of the graph without any lighting changes.**

```
m=5;
g=GridGraph[{m,m},VertexCoordinates->({#[[1]],0,#[[2]]}&/@((Tuples[Range[m]-1,2]-(m-1)/2)/(m-1))),GraphHighlightStyle->"Thick"];
HighlightGraph[g,PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g,9,17]]]
Clear[g,m]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: try using the option `BaseStyle -> Lighting -> "Neutral"` in `Graph[...]`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Animate[
 t = RotationTransform[Pi/a, {1, 0, 1}];
 pp = {#[[1]], 
     0, #[[2]]} & /@ ((Tuples[Range[m] - 1, 2] - (m - 1)/2)/(m - 1));
 f = {#[[1]], #[[3]]} & /@ t[pp];
 m = 5;
 g = GridGraph[{m, m}, VertexCoordinates -> f, 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"];
 HighlightGraph[g, PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g, 9, 17]]], {a, 1.0,
   5.}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, nice. That is what I wanted. And if the vertex disks were also rotating - changing their shape from circle to ellipse - it would be even better. But there is probably no easy solution.

Comment: I managed to imitate 2D `GridGraph` in `Graphics3D`.

Answer (score 3):

- `m` is dimension of `m*m` grid graph
- `r` is radius (size) of vertex
- `{p,q}` are strating and ending point of Hamiltonian path

---

`GridGraph` is emulated by `Graphics3D` to allow 3D rotation of 2D graph.

```
m=5;r=0.08;
{p,q}={9,17};
g=GridGraph[{m,m}];
li=Join[Table[{{j,i+r,0},{j,i+1-r,0}},{i,m-1},{j,m}],Table[{{i+r,j,0},{i+1-r,j,0}},{i,m-1},{j,m}]];
hli=((List@@@EdgeList[PathGraph[FindHamiltonianPath[g,p,q]]])/.Thread[Range[m^2]->Tuples[Range[m],{2}]]/.{{x1_Integer,y_Integer},{x2_Integer,y_Integer}}:>If[x1>x2,{{x1-r,y},{x2+r,y}},{{x1+r,y},{x2-r,y}}]/.{{x_Integer,y1_Integer},{x_Integer,y2_Integer}}:>If[y1>y2,{{x,y1-r},{x,y2+r}},{{x,y1+r},{x,y2-r}}])/.{x_,y_}/;NumericQ[x]->{x,y,0};
Graphics3D[{{RGBColor[{104,129,166}/256],Line/@li},{RGBColor[{217,127,127}/256],EdgeForm[{Thick,RGBColor[{178,0,0}/256]}],Cylinder[{{#[[1]],#[[2]],-0.001},{#[[1]],#[[2]],0.001}},r]&/@Tuples[Range[m],{2}]},{RGBColor[{178,0,0}/256],Thick,Line/@hli}},Boxed->False,Lighting->AmbientLight[White],SphericalRegion->True,RotationAction->"Clip",ViewPoint->{0,0,2}]
Clear[g,m,r,li,hli,p,q]
```

[image]